# How to close context menu in Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I am developing an Application using Primefaces 6.1.

In that, I used two pages, In my first page I used `p:contextMenu` and when I right click on that page, the menu automatically shows after that It couldn't hide it when I go to second page.

Help me to solve this issue.

**Issue:**

[image]

Comment: add more details like relevant source code for us to help you.

Comment: Can you show the code related to the `p:contextMenu`?

Comment: Don't show 'relevant' code or related code, show a [mcve]