# context menu not closing in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

In reference to this SO question [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808026/how-to-close-context-menu-in-primefaces), I am also facing this issue. Just adding extra information as I don't have privilege to edit question. Followings are the attached images and code:

Page 1:
[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tolU6.png)

Page 2:
[Second Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQRnc.png)

Code:

```
<p:contextMenu for="hosttable1" id="menu" widgetVar="contextMenu">
    <p:menuitem value="View Cable Combination" update=":formcable:cabDetail"
        oncomplete="PF('cabDialog').show()" />
    <p:menuitem value="View Support Document"
        actionListener="#{dialogFrameworkBean.showDialog()}" />
    <p:menuitem value="Upload Document" actionListener="#{fileupload.showDialog()}" />
</p:contextMenu>
```

Following code executes when Menu item is clicked:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().clear();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update("pnlContent"); // pnlContent refers to center layout
```

**NOTE:** This is single page application.
Let me know if more information is required.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you try something like adding `PF('contextMenu').hide()` in e.g. the onclick of the menuItem? or similar? (see the [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.contextmenu.js))

Comment: I am populating menu items through java bean. `onclick` is also executed programmatically. So, how to call `PF('contextMenu').close()`  in java bean?

Comment: Start by adding an onclick programmetically to the menuItem. Starti with just an 'alert' in it...And btw, your menuItems are in xhtml....!!!!

Comment: It is already added and working that's why navigation from one page to another page is working. Can you tell how to get `p:ContextMenu` or any View programmatically?
MenuItems of ContextMenu are in xhtml.

Comment: There is **NO** onclick visible in your code, so for me there is none...

Comment: i dont need to execute onclick event on menu item as i am facing this problem when i move to second page from menubar on north layout.the context menu is not disappearing when i switch to second page. Please see the referred question link.

Comment: But you **close** the contextMenu in the onclick on the current page so it is not visible on the second page

Comment: "Following code executes when Menu item is clicked" - which menu item? Why is it clearing the view map? `pnlContent refers to center layout` - PF advises to not update layout at all, instead update its content.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov    when click  Menu Item from north layout and move to second page context menu from page1 does not disappear and it  still appear on page2.